# Using HttpContextAccessor in a .NET 4.6 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a .NET Core project (a class library) that also targets .NET 4.6, which needs to be able to access the current HTTP context. I see that we can no longer use the static `HttpContext.Current`, and have to inject an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor`. Is this something I can still use inside something like a Web API project targeting .NET 4.6? So far, I can't get `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` to return anything but null.

Comment: Did you register `HttpContextAccessor`?

Comment: So, you want the same code to work both on ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core? I'm not sure that's possible in this case.

Comment: @ademcaglin Well from what I understand, you have to use IApplicationBuilder to register it, which I don't have in ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks @svick. Maybe I can do something around lazily getting the request details.

Answer (score 2):

For the class library I think you might want to pass the relevant variables/objects via constructor or methods.  It's good practice, because your class library wont break if you reference it in a console app without a httpcontext, for example.

If you're inside a controller method, you can just use Request or Response.

Comment: Hmm, well it's for a logging library, which needs to log quite a lot of details about the HTTP request, so I'd rather not have to specify all the request details whenever someone needs to log something.